# Gemfire, JMX Manager startup to fail because: 'HTTP service failed to start'

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I created gemfire instance and started a locator, and I was also able to access the HTTP application from browser. Another day when I logged again and start gfsh to connect gemfire install using following command, 


**gfsh>connect**


it gave following output,

```
gfsh>connect
Connecting to Locator at [host=localhost, port=10334] ..
Exception caused JMX Manager startup to fail because: 'HTTP service failed to start'
```

Even on connecting to locator,

```
gfsh>connect --locator=localhost[40405]
Connecting to Locator at [host=localhost, port=40405] ..
Exception caused JMX Manager startup to fail because: 'HTTP service failed to start'
```

Comment: Can you give some more details as to how you initially started the server and the locator? It seems like there might well be a port conflict on the HTTP port (default 7070) which is used for both the admin REST (gfsh) comms as well as the developer REST API.

Comment: yeah Jens, I had started a Gemfire instance in the beginning then after using that instance I think that instance was not shutdown gracefully and hence the service is running in the background, this could be the reason.
   But now I am also not able to close/shutdown that Gemfire instance which is running in the background.

Comment: If you absolutely do not need the embedded HTTP services running (i.e. are not using them) then you can disable the HTTP services by setting the GemFire HTTP service (`gemfire.http-service-port`) port to **0**.  This should avoid issues around HTTP during startup/shutdown.